# What does the phrase "ravir l'adhesion de" mean?

Tags: expressions, traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

What does the phrase "*ravir l'adhesion de*" mean?

Example ([source](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/15235/15235-h/15235-h.htm)):

> Vraiment, vous avez tort d'accuser la popularité de vous **ravir l'adhésion de** tant d'intelligences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tough one. "*Ravir*" (here) means steal, but in a subtle way, and often in the rules. For example in a race, if A is leading the whole race but B get in first place right at the end and wins the race, one could say "*B lui a ravi la victoire*".

It can also be used for opinions and elections, (I believe that's the case in your example) : like if voters are mostly voting for A and after a speech, B gains a lot of supporters from A, "*ravir*" could be used too. It implies "in the rules, but kind of sneaky", and often "at the very last moment"

"*Adhésion*" means the support of other people. "*Ils adhèrent à mes idées*" : They agree with my ideas. It's hard to tell with no context, but it could be political, or taking sides in a debate, or something like that.

So "ravir l'adhésion" means stealing or simply gaining the agreement and support of people who were before agreeing to someone else, most likely a competitor.

---

In your sentence, the author also used "*intelligences*" in lieu of "intelligent people". So one person lost the support and agreement of a number of intelligent people, and is blaming it on popularity. The person speaking says they are wrong to do so.

Comment: So, perhaps, "_ravir l'adhesion de_" = "to win the support of"?

Comment: @Geremia Pretty much, yes ! Also, remember that "*ravir*" means that you "stole" what you got, or at least got it from someone else. I don't know if "win" can mean that, maybe it can.